# Reversing Dot Product Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

Let $w,y, z \in R^n$ be vectors and $\sum_1^n w_i = 1$.

Suppose that $z$ and $w$ are both known and we are trying to solve for $y$.

It is given that $$z = \frac{y}{w^t \cdot y}$$ is it possible to solve for $y$?

As far as I could get:

$$(w^t \cdot y )z = y$$

$$w^t \cdot y \cdot z = y$$

Then let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with entries $w_1, ..., w_n$ and zeros everywhere else.

$$z^t \cdot D \cdot y = y$$

which implies that $z D = \mathbb{I}_n$, which is obviously **wrong** because the dimensions of $z D$ are (1 x n)(n x n) = (1 x n), which does not agree with the right hand side.

Comment: Going from $(w^t\cdot y)z$ to $w^t\cdot y \cdot z$ is at least misleading because the second dot is scalar multiplication, not a vector dot product, and wrong if you intend to go to $w^t(y\cdot z)$.  The last has a dot product without a transpose of a vector, so the dimensions do not match already.

Comment: My linear algebra is rusty.  Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to determine $y$.  From $z=\frac y{w^t\cdot y}$ we can see that we can multiply $y$ by any scalar without changing $z$.  In fact we can multiply both sides by $w^t$ and find $w^t\cdot z=1$.  If that is true, $y$ can be any vector proportional to $z$.  If it is not true, there is no solution.